# A general term meaning between 10 and 19

Tags: word-request

Between 20 and 29- we can say in the twenties.
Between 30 and 39 - we can say in the thirties.
And so on. But what about the range from 10 to 19? Tenties? Is there a general term for it?

Comment: It's not accurate but the best guess I could provide is "teens". To be accurate "teens" is a term for 13-19 and many times used for the age of adolescence. But since your adolescence doesn't necessarily start at you 13th birthday and doesn't necessarily end at your 19th birthday, I'd say "teens" would be appropriate. A more better answer is possible if you could provide the context.

Comment: [*Denarian*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denarian#English) exists, but I don't know how many people will know what you mean. Moreover, the word isn't registered by mainstream dictionaries.

Comment: Another way to express the same idea would be to say they're *in the second decade of life*.

Comment: You are talking about ages, right? In math or counting, for example, you would say *tens*.

Answer (score 2):

**Teens** is the word to use.

> Most High School kids are in their teens.